# How to clone single XML from hierarchy based on matching XmlNode in C#

Tags: c#, xml, clone

Here is the XML structure:

```
<root>
    <listOfItems>
        <item>
            <lineItem>1</lineItem>
            <itemDetail>
                <partNum>A1</partNum>
                <color>red</color>
                <qty>4</qty>
            </itemDetail>
        </item>
        <item>
            <lineItem>2</lineItem>
            <itemDetail>
                <partNum>B2</partNum>
                <color>blue</color>
                <qty>2</qty>
            </itemDetail>
        </item>
        <item>
            <lineItem>3</lineItem>
            <itemDetail>
                <partNum>C3</partNum>
                <color>green</color>
                <qty>1</qty>
            </itemDetail>
        </item>
    </listOfItems>
</root>
```

Knowing that the partNum is B2, how would I be able to clone the entire item B2 belongs to so I have 2 identical B2 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [CloneNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.clone?view=netcore-3.1) function to copy the node and [AppendChild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild?view=netcore-3.1) to attach it to the relevant place in the hierarchy.

```
// find the node
var target = doc.SelectSingleNode("root/listOfItems/item/itemDetail/partNum[text()='B2']");

// clone
var clonedNode = target.ParentNode.CloneNode(true);

// attach
target.ParentNode.ParentNode.AppendChild(clonedNode);
```

Comment: Thank you so much EyIM. This of course is a very simplified version of what I required and this helped put me on the right track to complete a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a System.Xml.Linq solution.

```
//Load the XML Document
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xDocPath);

//Find the XMLNode
XElement xB2 = xdoc.Root.Element("listOfItems").Elements("item").FirstOrDefault(it => it.Element("itemDetail").Element("partNum").Value.Equals("B2"));

//Clone the XMLNode
XElement xB2Copy = new XElement(xB2);
```

The XElement xB2 is linked to the xdoc.
The XElement xB2Copy is not linked to xdoc.

You would have to add it first, here are some examples.

```
xdoc.Root.Element("listOfItems").Add(xB2Copy);

xB2.AddAfterSelf(xB2Copy);

xB2.AddBeforeSelf(xB2Copy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication166
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement listOfItems = doc.Descendants("listOfItems").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement itemB = listOfItems.Elements("item").Where(x =>  x.Descendants("partNum").Any(y => (string)y == "B2")).FirstOrDefault();

            listOfItems.Add(XElement.Parse(itemB.ToString()));
        }
    }
 
}
```